# Generate range of dates using CTE Oracle

Tags: oracle, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I want to generate a range of days between two different dates using recursive WITH clause in Oracle.

```
WITH CTE_Dates (cte_date) AS
  ( SELECT CAST(TO_DATE('10-02-2017', 'DD-MM-YYYY') AS DATE) cte_date FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT CAST( (cte_date + 1) AS DATE) cte_date
  FROM CTE_Dates
  WHERE TRUNC(cte_date) + 1 <= TO_DATE('20-02-2017', 'DD-MM-YYYY')
  )
SELECT * FROM CTE_Dates
```

The returned results are completely other than expected:

```
10-02-2017
09-02-2017
08-02-2017
07-02-2017
06-02-2017
... (unlimited)
```

The expected results:

```
10-02-2017
11-02-2017
...
19-02-2017
20-02-2017
```

Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production.

**Edit:**
As I understood, this is a known Bug in Oracle, the bug exists through Oracle 11.2.0.2 and it was fixed in 11.2.0.3.

Altarnative solution:

```
SELECT TRUNC (TO_DATE('10-02-2017', 'DD-MM-YYYY') + ROWNUM -1) dt
  FROM DUAL
 CONNECT BY ROWNUM  <= (TO_DATE('20-02-2017', 'DD-MM-YYYY') - (TO_DATE('10-02-2017', 'DD-MM-YYYY')))
```

Comment: When I run your code as posted it generates 11 rows from  `2017-02-10`
to `2017-02-20`, that is your expected results. Please try again.

Comment: What version of the database are you using? Recursive WITH clause is only supported on 11gR2 and later

Comment: Unrelated, but: the `CAST(... AS DATE)` is useless. A simple `TO_DATE('10-02-2017', 'DD-MM-YYYY')` is doing exactly the same thing.

Comment: Also: if you want the rows sorted, you need to apply an `order by` to the overall `select` statement

Comment: @APC which version do you use?
My database version is:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production.

Comment: @AlexPoole - As I explain in the answer I just posted, that is a well known **bug** in recursive CTE up to Oracle 11.2, fixed in 12.1.

Comment: @mathguy - I'm not seeing it in 11.2.0.4, but OK. Looks like bug 11840579, fixed in 11.2.0.3 patchset, not just 12.1. (Also the new features guide says [RCTE was introduced in 11.2.0.1](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/wnsql.htm#SQLRF50926), not 11.1. Column aliases in the declaration were introduced then too, I guess as they're related. The error you get trying to use them in earlier versions is interesting...)

Comment: @AlexPoole - 11.2.0.4 rings a bell; I think 11.2.0.4 wasn't available as Express Edition (when I didn't know I can download the Enterprise Edition for free if it's strictly for learning, and by the time I learned that, I decided to learn Oracle 12 so I never downloaded 11.2.0.4) But yes, I think whoever told me about the bug said it was fixed in 11.2.0.4, I just forgot. Re: release of RCTE, I always get it wrong (confused with PIVOT - then PIVOT must be 11.1 and RCTE 11.2). Thanks for clarifying, I will edit my answer to reflect this. (Also, I deleted my response to APC as it was incorrect.)

Comment: I found it: https://community.oracle.com/thread/3974408

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was a known bug in recursive CTE's in Oracle 11 (specifically with regard to date arithmetic). Fixed in Oracle 12. Exactly that behavior: whether you add or subtract in your code, the engine always subtracts, it never adds.

**EDIT**: Actually, as Alex Poole pointed out in a Comment to the original post, the bug exists through Oracle 11.2.0.2 and it was fixed in 11.2.0.3. **End edit**

Alas I am not a paying customer, so I can't quote chapter and verse, but with a little bit of Googling you will find links to this (including on OTN where I was involved in a few threads discussing this and other bugs in recursive CTEs - some were fixed, some are still bugs in Oracle 12.1).

**Added** - here is one of those discussions: https://community.oracle.com/thread/3974408

Answer (score 3):

Unless you really need to use the WITH clause there is another solution to get the expected result by using the CONNECT BY clause.

```
SELECT TO_DATE('10-02-2017', 'DD-MM-YYYY') AS date_range
  FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT TO_DATE('10-02-2017', 'DD-MM-YYYY') + LEVEL  
  FROM dual 
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (TO_DATE('20-02-2017', 'DD-MM-YYYY') - TO_DATE('10-02-2017', 'DD-MM-YYYY'));
```

Comment: Why include a union (which should probably be union-all anyway)? If you change the second branch 's select list to get `... + LEVEL - 1` and add 1 to the connect-by limit, it will include the date you're currently unioning anyway.

Comment: Yes, I could have used just one SELECT statement, I simply wanted to be closer to his initial solution. My answer was meant only to show an alternative to the WITH clause. About the UNION ALL, you're absolutely right, that's my mistake.

Comment: I see, though the union-all in that is part of the recursive CTE structure. I'm not sure if the original question implies they specifically want to use RCTE and alternatives aren't needed, but guess only the OP can answer that *8-)

Comment: I believe the OP is asking specifically about the observed bug (recursive CTE giving the wrong result), more so than "how else can I achieve the desired result".

Answer (score 2):

Maybe reverse order of the recursion solves the problem:

```
with cte_dates (cte_date) as ( 
    select cast(to_date('20-02-2017', 'DD-MM-YYYY') as date) cte_date from dual
    union all
    select  cast((cte_date - 1) as date)  cte_date
    from cte_dates
    where cast(cte_date as date) > to_date('10-02-2017', 'DD-MM-YYYY')
    )
select * from cte_dates 
order by cte_date 
;

2017-02-10
2017-02-11
2017-02-12
...
2017-02-18
2017-02-19
2017-02-20
```

Note: cast date as date needed due to yet another bug by RCTE in 11gR2

[Old discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586653/recursive-sql-giving-ora-01790)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a recursive WITH clause, you just need a table where number of rows > number of dates you want to generate :

```
WITH
 dates
 AS
 (SELECT 
   TO_DATE('10-02-2017', 'DD-MM-YYYY') + (rownum - 1)
  FROM
   all_tables
  WHERE 1=1 
  AND rownum < (TO_DATE('20-02-2017', 'DD-MM-YYYY') - TO_DATE('10-02-2017', 'DD-MM-YYYY')) + 2
 )
SELECT 
 *
FROM
 dates
```

Comment: but for what it's worth, your query worked fine for me